# How to draw a rectangle in WPF at a specific x,y screen location?

Tags: wpf, draw, rectangles

In C#, WPF I've created a rectangle:

```
        Rectangle myRgbRectangle = new Rectangle();
        myRgbRectangle.Width = 1;
        myRgbRectangle.Height = 1;
        SolidColorBrush mySolidColorBrush = new SolidColorBrush();
```

Yes, I really just want it to be 1 pixel by 1 pixel. And I want to change the color based on the variable height like so:

```
        mySolidColorBrush.Color = Color.FromArgb(255, 0, 0, (byte)height);
        myRgbRectangle.Fill = mySolidColorBrush;
```

Now, how do I draw at a specific x,y location on the screen? I do have a grid (myGrid) on my MainWindow.xaml.

Thanks!

---

Here's the pertinent code:

```
        myRgbRectangle.Width = 1;
        myRgbRectangle.Height = 1;
        SolidColorBrush mySolidColorBrush = new SolidColorBrush();

        int height;
        for (int i = 0; i < ElevationManager.Instance.heightData.GetLength(0); i++)
            for (int j = 0; j < ElevationManager.Instance.heightData.GetLength(1); j++)
            {
                height = ElevationManager.Instance.heightData[i, j] / 100;
                // Describes the brush's color using RGB values. 
                // Each value has a range of 0-255.
                mySolidColorBrush.Color = Color.FromArgb(255, 0, 0, (byte)height);
                myRgbRectangle.Fill = mySolidColorBrush;

                myCanvas.Children.Add(myRgbRectangle);
                Canvas.SetTop(myRgbRectangle, j);
                Canvas.SetLeft(myRgbRectangle, i);
```

And it's throwing this error: Specified Visual is already a child of another Visual or the root of a CompositionTarget.

Comment: How many such 1-pixel rectangles are you going to create?

Comment: A ton of these 3600 x 3600. I really just want to draw colored pixels.

Comment: Well, that would roughly be 13 million rectangles. Impossible! And you already got that answer (as comment) on your previous question: [WriteableBitmap](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.windows.media.imaging.writeablebitmap.aspx) is the **only** sensible approach.

Comment: I don't understand why this is impossible. And I've been told that WriteableBitmap has a memory leak. Also, I can't use 'unsafe' code.

Comment: It would mean to add 13 million child elements to a Canvas. Go ahead and try it. You'll find out that even 13000 would be a problem.

Comment: Why is it so difficult to just draw a pixel at x,y of color RGB in WPF? I've written for dozens of systems in different languages and IDEs... I've never had so much trouble doing the simplest thing! This is driving me nuts. All I want is DrawPixel(x,y,RGB)!

Comment: This is simply because WPF is all about vector graphics. It tries to get rid of pixels and draws everything by means of filled areas with boundaries defined by floating-point coordinates. See [Graphics and Multimedia](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms742562.aspx).

Comment: @zetar, if you want DrawPixel, then use something that's built out of pixels, i.e., WriteableBitmap. All the rest of WPF is built around vector graphics, not raster (pixel) graphics. If you want pixels, WriteableBitmap is exactly the right tool for the job, and if you refuse to use it, you're setting yourself up to fail.

Comment: The 'unsafe' code label scares me and the client. I'm looking at ArcGIS now

Comment: Unsafe only means the the CLR can not verify it. see this [MSDN article](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/t2yzs44b.aspx)

Answer (score 19):

You need to use a [`Canvas`](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/fk49wtc1.aspx) istead of a [`Grid`](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.windows.controls.grid.aspx). You use coordinates to position elements in a `Canvas` versus Column and Row in a `Grid`.

Definition of a Canvas:

> Defines an area within which you can explicitly position child elements by using coordinates that are relative to the Canvas area.

You would then use [`Canvas.SetTop`](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.windows.controls.canvas.settop.aspx) and [`Canvas.SetLeft`](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.windows.controls.canvas.setleft.aspx) Properties like this (*assuming that your canvas is named `myCanvas`*):

```
 myCanvas.Children.Add(myRgbRectangle);
 Canvas.SetTop(myRgbRectangle, 50);
 Canvas.SetLeft(myRgbRectangle, 50);
```

---

**Edit**

Based on your edit, it is like I said you are adding the same rectangle more than once. You need to be creating it in your For Loop each time you add it. Something like this.

```
for (int i = 0; i < ElevationManager.Instance.heightData.GetLength(0); i++) 
    for (int j = 0; j < ElevationManager.Instance.heightData.GetLength(1); j++) 
    { 
        Rectangle rect = new Rectangle();
        rect.Width = 1;
        rect.Height = 1;
        height = ElevationManager.Instance.heightData[i, j] / 100; 
        // Describes the brush's color using RGB values.  
        // Each value has a range of 0-255. 
        mySolidColorBrush.Color = Color.FromArgb(255, 0, 0, (byte)height); 
        rect.Fill = mySolidColorBrush; 

        myCanvas.Children.Add(rect); 
        Canvas.SetTop(rect, j); 
        Canvas.SetLeft(rect, i); 
    }
```

Comment: I've got a Canvas, 'myCanvas', too. How would I explicitly position the x,y of the rect in the Canvas?

Comment: It's throwing this error: Specified Visual is already a child of another Visual or the root of a CompositionTarget. Any ideas?

Comment: @zetar have you already added your rectangle to another Container object?

Comment: I updated the original question so you could see all the code... no, I don't think the rectangle is added to another Container object.

Comment: @zetar Looking at the Code you just added you are adding the same rectangle to your Canvas Multiple Times. I have just edited my answer to correspond

Comment: That doesn't seem to work... it's not crashing, but it's not drawing anything. From Clemens answer above it just flat out seems impossible to do what I want: DrawPixel(x,y,RGB). I

Comment: @zetar With the test that I did it took about 20 seconds to draw 100x100 points, So as was said earlier you probably should be using a `WritableBitmap`.